# How to use a custom JSON map in Highmaps

Tags: json, highcharts

I would like to use a custom world map with Highmaps. I used [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org) (great tool!) to reduce the number of vertices, and checked the JSON code with a JSON validator and imported it in QGIS, where it works fine. But I don't succeed in convincing Highmaps to use it:

I use:

```
series : [
{
    data : data,
    //mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
    mapData: 'etc/BNDA25_CTY.json',
    ...
}
```

I haven't found any example (code) of custom JSON maps so far. Guess it's pretty straightforward. But how does it work? Does the JSON to be made in a specific way?

[Here](https://gegslive-test.unepgrid.ch/etc/BNDA25_CTY.json) is the JSON code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to assign your JSON object as `Highcharts.map('name')`, where name is a value which we will use to the import.
2. Highcharts has the option `joinBy` set to `hc-key` by default. I can't see this property in your JSON, so we need to change this value, let's say to:

   ```
    joinBy: 'ISO3CD',
   ```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.joinBy

3. We need to set keys for the data, to:

   ```
    keys: ['ISO3CD', 'value'],
   ```

   API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.keys

Final demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q34tue8a/

It will be better to reassign your JSON to the new one with defined the `Highcharts.map` and attach it as a script, but I left this to you ;)

Comment: Ah, great! Can the customMap be loaded from the »series« section too? Like »*series: { mapData: 'customMap', ...}*«? As my code indicates »*$('#container').highcharts('Map', {...*«, and yours »*Highcharts.mapChart('container', { chart: { map: 'customMap'}*«, I wonder where the difference is and if I need to use your syntax or can work with mine too?

Comment: @luftikus143 Which version of the Highcharts/Highmaps do you use? Seems like you use the old constructor.

Comment: I am pointing to the most recent library of Highmaps. So, am I using an »old« way of constructing, which has meanwhile changed? Any tip where I can see the changes it forces in the code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @luftikus143 ah sorry, my mistake I haven't noticed that you use the jQuery way to render the map. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started#initialize-the-map - as you can see the only difference is that I don't use the jQuery. And yes, the customMap can be loaded from the `series` section too, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bh5vafet/